# android gridview sends multiple request on scroll up and down

Tags: android, gridview, picasso, imagedownload

I am using gridview in android which loading images from AWS s3. Also using picaso library & calling it in getview of adapter.
Now if I scroll up & down, it sends multiple request for same images. Also those images taking lot of time to load causing performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

IF the `getView()` method is also called multiple times, this could indicate that the width/height of your view is set to "wrap content" instead of "fill_parent" or "match_parent". this causes the rendering system to constantly calculate how big the container view is, causing a lot of calls to getView